# clone jira epic with child issues

Tags: jira, clone, children

Although there are [awesome](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JCPP/overview) [extensions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1218652/deep-clone-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud) to do this, I am looking for a native solution.

Answer (score 2):

How I did it using Jira Automation.

[image: Jira Automation recipe]

Detailed screenshots that require configuration:

Clone epic and set assignee to `User who triggered the event`.
[image: Clone issue (epic)]

Create variable using `{{createdIssue}}`.
[image: Create variable]

Add an epic link to cloned child issues and set assignee to `User who triggered the event`.
[image: Clone issue (child issues)]